# Navigate path through the 2d list by input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop

How to navigate path through the 2d list using this inputs: u, d, l, r to represent up, down ,left ,right, respectively. And the reference would be the list[0][0]=1(see ex. fig. ) which uses the python reverse method which make the [0][0] appear to the bottom. In case the move will make go out of bounds it will just ignore the move and proceed to the next move. (Example: an input of uuddlrlr would make go up twice, down twice, left, right, then left, and right again). Which will end up in the list[0][1] = 8.

The fig.1 uses the python reverse method which make the [0][0] appear to the bottom.

```
list = [[0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0],
        [0,8,0,0]]


I have try this code though but ain't working
def __init__(self, move):
    self.move = move
    self.x = ''

def inputMove(self, Monster):
    self.content = Monster.getVal()

    for self.row in reversed(self.content):
        print(self.row)
    print(isinstance(self.move,str))

    try:
        self.i = 0
        self.j = 0
        self._doraPower = 10
        isinstance(self.move, str)

        if self.move == 'u':
            try:
                self.i+=1
                self.content[self.i][self.j]
                for self.row in reversed(self.content):
                    print(self.row)
                if self._doraPower >= self.content[self.i][self.j]:
                    print('dora wins')
                else:
                    print('Coordinates of last room visited:',self.i,',',self.j)
            except IndexError:
                pass

        if self.move == 'd':
            try:
                self.i-=1
                self.content[self.i][self.j]
                print(self.i)
                for self.row in reversed(self.content):
                    print(self.row)
                if self.i > 0:    
                    if self._doraPower >= self.content[self.i][self.j]:
                        print('dora wins')
                    else:
                        print('Coordinates of last room visited:',self.i,',',self.j)
                else:
                    pass
            except IndexError:
                pass

        if self.move == 'r':
            try:
                self.j+=1
                self.content[self.i][self.j]

                for self.row in reversed(self.content):
                    print(self.row)
                
                if self._doraPower >= self.content[self.i][self.j]:
                    print('dora wins')
                else:
                    print('Coordinates of last room visited:',self.i,',',self.j)
            except IndexError:
                pass
            
        if self.move == 'l':
            try:
                self.j-=1
                self.content[self.i][self.j]
                print(self.i, self.j)
                if self.j > 0:
                    if self._doraPower >= self.content[self.i][self.j]:
                        print('dora wins')
                        print(self.content[self.i][self.j])
                    else:
                        print('Coordinates of last room visited:',self.i,',',self.j)
                else:
                    pass

            except IndexError:
                pass

        else:
            pass

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it belongs inside a class. Also, self.content[self.i][self.j] doesn't appear to be doing anything. As for the index error, I would double-check the input data to make sure that's not the problem.

Does Monster.getVal() return a matrix like list?

Comment: If index error it will just pass because the code catches the error